# how Width units like rem,em and px makes the openui5 responsive?

Tags: sapui5

Hi I am new to OpenUI5 and the logo says "Code Once work on all devices" but like when we use px, rem and em as width units for controls they take standard width which will not resize according to the screen size then how does the responsiveness works as logo says. Why do OpenUI5 claims that is fully responsive which is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. If we use width, height, etc, it will be not responsive. So we need to use layouts, percents, anchors, etc. Also we remember that OpenUI5 extended version of jquery.